# String search Regular expressions VB?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

In Excel VB I'm trying to search a string for a 4 digit number denoting a year, ie. ***"The man was born in the year 1986, it was a sunny day"***, I am trying to extract the ***"1986"*** from this string. It seems like using regular expressions would be my best option however I'm unfamiliar with them, is the regular expression for a 4 digit number something like ***"\d{4}"*** ?,

if I find that my string contains such a number is there an efficient way for getting the start and end point of the string for extraction? I have ideas on how to do it but they seem very inefficient, is there a fast way to find and extract this data?

pseudocode:

```
dim bool As boolean
bool = cells(d, 1).Value.contains(\d{4})

if bool then
   'extract string
end if
```

Comment: VBA or VB.NET?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: noted, sorry for the mistake